# ASP Substitute for User-Agent PHP

Tags: php, asp-classic

I've been using a snippet of PHP to detect an end-user's user-agent and deliver device-specific content based on the user-agent. The basic logic employed is...."if you're an iPad, goto this URL...if you're an iPhone, goto this URL...if you're neither, continue on your merry way and load the html that follows".

Everything's been working great with the PHP snippet. However, these files now need to be served from an ASP server and I have no idea how to replicate the solution in ASP. So, I'm asking for help here. There's an 'ASP expert' on the job already. But, we're in our second week of not having a solution. Anything you can do to help is definitely appreciated.

The example below shows the PHP I've been using. The real HTML has been removed because of its length.

```
<?php

//setting the iPhone / iPod / iPad browser variables

$iphone = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$ipod = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$ipad = strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");

//detecting device browser

if ($iphone == true){
header( 'Location: Webinar_iPhone.mp4' ) ;
}
if ($ipod == true){
header( 'Location: Webinar_iPhone.mp4' ) ;
}
if ($ipad == true){
header( 'Location: Webinar_iPad.mp4' ) ;
}
else {

?>

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
This is a test
</BODY>
</HTML>

<?php

}

?>
```

Thanks,

Shayne

Comment: You've got an "expert" on it who hasn't figured out how to detect the user agent for over a week?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean classic ASP? You would want to look at `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")`

I haven't tested this, but to simulate what you want, you'd do something like:

```
Dim iPhone
iPhone = InStr(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT"), "iPhone")

If( iPhone > 0 ) Then
     Response.Redirect("Webinar_iPhone.mp4") 
     Resonse.End()
End If
```

Comment: Looking at the PHP, he wants `Response.Redirect("Webinar_iPhone.mp4")`

Comment: if I was to be pedantic, you also need a `Response.End()` otherwise the script will continue executing :)

Comment: @RichardBenson You're right. Been stuck in the .NET world for too long. It took everything for me not to add semi-colons at the end of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little something we were using on our homepage to redirect for mobile users. You could probably adapt it for your needs.

```
dim u,b,v
set u=Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_USER_AGENT")
set b=new RegExp
set v=new RegExp
b.Pattern="android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile|o2|opera mini|palm( os)?|plucker|pocket|pre\/|psp|smartphone|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce; (iemobile|ppc)|xiino"
v.Pattern="1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-"

b.IgnoreCase=true
v.IgnoreCase=true
b.Global=true
v.Global=true

if b.test(u) or v.test(Left(u,4)) then response.redirect("SITE-NAME-HERE") end if
```